# I have a query that does 2 sums, and then the first will subtract the second, but in some cases the second is null

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

I have a query (in MS-Query, MSQRY32.EXE) that does 2 sums, and then the first will subtract the second, but in some cases the second is null, how do I go over this?

```
(Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN m.mqtd END)- 
Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=12 THEN m.mqtd END))
```

This is the part of the query, but sometimes one of them or both are null, so how do I do this?

Comment: are you really using Access?  Is this a pass-through query?  Access doesn't use CASE it uses IIF

Comment: yes, it works if i dont try to subtract. only i get null values when one of the sum contains null...

Comment: Perhaps you better show us a fuller example of your query. You can skip the irrelevant columns.

Comment: Lordy... anything we can do to convince you to do the query natively in MS Access, and then query the resulting query in MS Query / Excel (Whatever app you are launching MS Query from)?

Comment: Now I realize that I need to use MS query, because I can autoupdate the excel data on fly. no copy paste...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(IIf(Sum1 Is Null,0,Sum1) -
IIf(Sum2 Is Null,0,Sum2))`

Comment: but in my access I can't do "Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN m.mqtd END) as 'Sum1'"... it just dont accept it!

Comment: In that case, this might be a better fit: `(nz(Sum1,0) - nz(Sum2,0))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I was perhaps unclear in my haste.  Here's how I would envision the solution: `(nz(Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN m.mqtd END),0) - nz(Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=12 THEN m.mqtd END),0))`  Does this work?

Comment: nop, i think I dont have the nz function... or so. is access 2003

Comment: It has nz(), I guarantee it. If it didn't, MS would have broken millions of DBs

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to store the results of the sums into local variables 
`Sum1 = ...`
and
`Sum2 = ...`
and then using the IIf syntax in the original post.

Comment: again, i don't see how your original query is working using a CASE statement in Access....Access doesn't have it, it uses IIF()

Comment: I dont know, but in the window panel the title is: "Microsoft query". So its not exactly access. You are right in access it gives me an error at the "case"

Answer (score 0):

First I'd ask whether it is appropriate to be summing nulls, and what you expect to get when you subtract a null from an non-null (or vice-versa).

Probably what you want to do is either eliminate records with nulls (`where m.mqtd is not null`) or to change all the null's to 0's (`nz(m.mqtd, 0)`)

Comment: yup... read only - just use it in the select wherever you are using m.mqtd

Comment: (Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=11 THEN (Nz(m.mqtd, 0)) END) -
Sum(CASE WHEN m.mcdmv=12 THEN (Nz(m.mqtd, 0)) END)) ||| it doesnt work